# Mutable File System vs Regular Files API in IPFS

Tags: ipfs

What's the difference between Mutable File System's (MFS) `read`:

```js
await ipfs.files.read('/some/stuff/success.txt')
```

and Regular Files API's `cat`:

```js
await ifps.cat(someFile)
```

Is it the fact that the cat method first searches your own node for the file requested, and if it can't find it there, it will attempt to find it on the broader IPFS network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter for `cat` is an IPFS Path, not a file path. An IPFS Path is basically all the variations on a content identifier.

`cat` will fetch the data from the local repo if it exists there, or ask the network if it does not.

`files.read` accepts an MFS path, which is a file path for a file you've already added to your IPFS repo - as well as an IPFS Path or CID object. If you pass an MFS path, a file or directory at that path must already be in the local repo already or the API will not find anything.

The documentation for `files.read`:

https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/FILES.md#filesread

The documentation for `cat`:

https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/FILES.md#cat

A good tutorial on the Regular Files API is here:

https://proto.school/#/regular-files-api/04

And one for MFS and `file.read`:

https://proto.school/#/mutable-file-system/10

And a tutorial on CIDs (content identifiers) is here:

https://proto.school/#/data-structures/04